# How to perform zooming in FlipView control Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I tried to perform zooming in flip view control but it does not work. I have used scroll viewer as parent and flip view control is child. Flip view item source is canvas.

Here my xaml code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollViewer 
        Name="ContentViewer" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" MinZoomFactor="1"
        MaxZoomFactor="3.0" ZoomMode="Enabled">
                <FlipView 
            Name="ImageContainer" UseTouchAnimationsForAllNavigation="True">
                </FlipView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Please guide me to perform zooming in flip view control.

Thanks,
Parthipan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScrollViewer should be child of flipview

Like this

```
<FlipView>
     <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                            MinZoomFactor="0.5"
                            MaxZoomFactor="2.5"
                            Margin="0" >
                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"
                          Stretch="Uniform" />
              </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```